# Adjacent JSX elements wrapping with Fela and React issues with parent component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

Adjacent JSX elements must be enclosed by a parent tag, which is causing me some issues with implementing [Fela](http://fela.js.org). I am new to all these technologies, and trying to ensure that I am applying them with best practices in mind.  Say I have a **`Page`** component and a fela component -- **`pageWrapperCss`** :

```
const PageWrapperCss = createComponent(
    (props) => (
        {   
            paddingTop: props.navbarHeight + 'px',
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            alignContent: 'stretch',
            flexGrow: 1,
            flexShrink: 0,
        }
    ), 'div'
);

const Page = ({view}, {cssVars}) => {
    // some logic here which may set TargetView = Dashboard component
    return (        
        <PageWrapperCss {...cssVars} >
            <TargetView />
        </PageWrapperCss>
    );
};

export default Page;
```

The TargetView component is composed of sections, which also have their css composed with Fela.  Below are the sections wrapped by a parent node -- **div**.  Therein lies the problem. Now I have a **div** node between my parent component -- **`PageWrapperCss`** -- which generates a **div** node with the attached classNames.

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
    render() {
        let { cssVars } = this.context;
        return (
        <div>
            <SectionWrapperCss {...cssVars}>
                <HeaderSection>
            </SectionWrapperCss>
            <SectionWrapperCss {...cssVars}>
                <BodySection />
            </SectionWrapperCss>
            <SectionWrapperCss sectionFlex="1" {...cssVars}>
                <AnotherSection />
            </SectionWrapperCss>
        </div>
        );  
    }       
}
```

Before I had **`PageWrapperCss`** component in the **`Dashboard`** component like the following, which worked fine; however I want to keep the Fela css logic within the component it relates to, so that I don't have to keep generating **`PageWrapperCss`** components in each target view.

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
    render() {
        let { cssVars } = this.context;
        return (
        <PageWrapperCss>
            // sections
        </PageWrapperCss>
        );  
    }       
}
```

***How have others dealt with this?***  Fela is pretty flexible, I could just render the css in the **`Page`** component, and persist the className via props to all the views, and add them to the parent node.

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
    render() {
        let { cssVars } = this.context;
        return (
        <div className={this.props.pageCss} >
            // sections
        </div>
        );  
    }       
}
```

thanks!